# Unable to acess - Push Git

Tags: git, github

I am facing the following error when executing a push in git:

Fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/usergit/project.git': failed to connect to 10.216.x.xxx port 8080: Time out

I already ran the unset proxy in git and also disabled the proxy in windows.

Comment: Can you ping the above IP address?? Are you able to telnet on 8080 port?

Comment: ipconfig /renew try to execute this

Comment: @harshavmb  Ping failed at this address

Comment: @ShivangAgarwal  I ran and the error continued

Comment: So, try to find out why it is failing? Any firewall in between? If you are on Windows run 'tracert <ip-address>'. It tells you where it's getting failed!

Comment: I do not know the source of this ip, I believe it was a proxy. But in this current network I do not use any. The current ip is another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTTPS cloning errors**
There are a few common errors when using HTTPS with Git. These errors usually indicate you have an old version of Git, or you don't have access to the repository.

Here's an example of an HTTPS error you might receive:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing
https://github.com/user/repo.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed

Error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing
https://github.com/user/repo.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed

Error: https://github.com/user/repo.git/info/refs not found: did you run git
update-server-info on the server?
```

**Check your Git version**

There's no minimum Git version necessary to interact with GitHub, but we've found version 1.7.10 to be a comfortable stable version that's available on many platforms. You can always download the latest version on the Git website.

**Ensure the remote is correct**

The repository you're trying to fetch must exist on GitHub, and the URL is case-sensitive.

You can find the URL of the local repository by opening the command line and typing `git remote -v:`

```
git remote -v
# View existing remotes
origin  https://github.com/github/reactivecocoa.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/github/reactivecocoa.git (push)

git remote set-url origin https://github.com/github/ReactiveCocoa.git
# Change the 'origin' remote's URL

git remote -v
# Verify new remote URL
origin  https://github.com/github/ReactiveCocoa.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/github/ReactiveCocoa.git (push)
```

Alternatively, you can change the URL through our GitHub Desktop application.

Provide an access token

If you have enabled two-factor authentication, or if you are accessing an organization that uses SAML single sign-on, you must provide a personal access token instead of entering your password for HTTPS Git.

**Check your permissions**

When prompted for a username and password, make sure you use an account that has access to the repository.

Tip: If you don't want to enter your username and password every time you interact with the remote repository, you can turn on password caching.

**Use SSH instead**

If you've previously set up SSH keys, you can use the SSH clone URL instead of HTTPS. For more information, see ["Which remote URL should I use?"](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/)

Answer (score 1):

> I believe it was a proxy. But in this current network I do not use any

Double-check for the presence of any proxy directive in:

```
git config -l
set
```

The second command displays the Windows environment variable.

If that fails, check if an ssh url might at least allows you to move forward:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:usergit/project.git
```